# How to remove everything after a certain character in Notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++

I need to remove everything after a certain character. For example in the following lines:

```
email:pass:text:text
email:pass:text:text
```

How would I remove everything past the second `:` so it ends up like this

```
email:pass
email:pass
```

Comment: Or match `^[^:\r\n]*:[^:\r\n]+\K.*` and replace with an empty string https://regex101.com/r/8Be9bX/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pattern `([^:]*:[^:]*)[^\n]*` and replace with `\1`. Search mode should be "regular expression".

Comment: Works fine for me. You probably have `. matches newline` ticked. Untick that.